# Start node app through ssh, stays running?

Tags: node.js, ssh

I have a raspberry PI on which I run a node server. To start and control the terminal on which the server runs I use desktop remote to remote control the raspberry. Now this method is really slow so I was wondering, since I only need a command line anyway if I couldn't just connect to my raspberry pi using ssh for example.

My question now, would be if I do so, can I navigate to my node folder, run my node file and then close the ssh connection? Will my Node server keep running and if so how would I access the terminal with the node session after closing the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is something like:

```
nohup node myapp.js &
```

This will make the app run in the background, and `nohup` prevents it from stopping when the connection closes.

This is a cheap and quick way to do this. A more appropriate way might be one of the following:

- Using something like docker to manage running applications.
- Using something like supervisord to do the same thing.
- Writing scripts for initd and turn it into a real 'service'.
- Changing the node application to fork & deamonize itself.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, in the case of nohup, is there a way for me to shut down the server again from the remote terminal if i reestablish the connection?

Comment: ah yea that works, last problem I have, is that the process still gets killed when I close the terminal, is there a way to work around that?

Comment: Yes I do, my Mac terminal asks me if I want to Terminate when I am closing the terminal which it only does when I have a process running on my terminal.

Comment: Are you sure it's killing the process though?

Comment: Yea, I can access the website it's hosting using the IP of my raspberry pi. I can access the website when the terminal is open, once I close the terminal the website cant be reached anymore.

Comment: That's really odd. Well, I have another suggestion that's probably pretty simple to do. Use `tmux` or `screen`. You basically start one of those utilities (which starts a new shell) and detach from the shell (`CTRL-A, D` or `CTRL-B, D` depending on config). What's nice is you can attach later again